# Multi Lingual C# application - Issue on getting Chinese Language selection option on typing English key combination

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a c# Winforms application using VS 2008 and DevExpress.

In one form, I need the some data to be added both in English and Chinese Language. So I placed separate textboxes for both Chinese and English and two buttons on

form. one Button click shows Chinese language section and changes Inputlanguage . Second button hides Chinese language section, Changes InputLanguage .

When I run the application, First time when I change to Chinese Language, I am getting Chinese language selection option on typing English letter combination. But

after returning to English, if I again go to Chinese data entry, I am not getting Chinese Language support on typing English.

But I am seeing the Language change on Taskbar.

Language Change  Code

```
//1st method

foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
{
    CName = lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToString();

    if (CName.StartsWith("Chinese")) //"English"
    {
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;

        break;
    }
}

//2nd Method

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
```

Please give me some advice

Comment: Do you try to debug it ?

Comment: Why do you even need to control the input language? Chinese users are perfectly capable of doing that themselves.

Comment: Just to add to your pain, there are two major versions of written Chinese: Simplified and Traditional.  Also, the dialectal variations (Macau, Hong Kong, Sigarpore, etc).  @VincentMcNabb is right, let the user select the input language.

Comment: 1) While debugging language is changing. Even I can see the change at Taskbar 2)We need two languages. Also the application is installed on system with default language English

Comment: 3)If the user is changing language from taskbar, then he may have to do it many times manually. So I want to do it from code using preferred language stored in DB

Comment: I tried this with normal windows forms project and controls( Not Devexpress form) still the issue not solved.

 If we change input language manually at Taskbar, I am getting Input Method Editor (IME). The Issue is only with language change from code.